# CoreML error: "Image is not expected type 32BGRA or 32ARGB"

Tags: ios, yolo, coreml

I use YOLO based detector with NMS on output. If I use `CoreML` directly, I get this error:

> Image is not expected type 32BGRA or 32ARGB, instead is Unsupported (875704422)

[image: CoreML model input and output formats]

Code to call looks like this:

```
do {
    // I write my own wrappers around `CoreMLHelpers`
    // If I pass image without crop, error is the same
    let inSize = CVPixelBuffer.Size(width: 1280, height: 640)
    let crop = CVPixelBuffer.Rect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inSize.width, height: inSize.height)
    if var buffer = self.preparedBuffer, buffer.size == inSize {
        imageBuffer.crop(rect: crop, outPixelBuffer: &buffer)
    } else {
        self.preparedBuffer = imageBuffer.crop(rect: crop, outSize: inSize)
    }
    
    let out = try model.prediction(image: self.preparedBuffer!, iouThreshold: 0.4, confidenceThreshold: 0.25)
    //..
} catch {
    NSLog("Detector error: \(error)")
}
```

I took example from Apple with `Vision` framework. No error occurs with same input:

```
let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cmSampleBuffer: buffer, orientation: vOrientation)
```

Code with `CoreML` is much easier to understand and anyway I need custom crop of specific area. So it prefer to stay with it. Do anyone has same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spend 2 days and find the issue. I forgot that my camera out in YUV format. `VNImageRequestHandler` knows about this format and convert inside by himself. So I changed the output format and everything works:

```
let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoOutput.videoSettings = [
    String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA
]
```